# How to add a new root element to a json string in t-sql

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I'm stumped on this for whatever reason. How do I add a new root element to the below json?

```
{
   "Test1":[{"TestValue1":"value1","TestValue2":"value2"}],
   "Test2":[{"TestValue1":"value1","TestValue2":"value2"}],
   "Test3":[{"TestValue1":"value1","TestValue2":"value2"}]
}
```

I'd like to add "Test4":[{"TestValue1":"value1","TestValue2":"value2"}]

I can read the data from a sql column with openjson and can update a property within one of the elements with json_modify but can't figure out how to add a full new element.

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a JSON object, so when you try to set `Test4` to something it will only update that property. Try adding `Test3` instead of `Test4`.

Comment: @LucasLaValva Yes you can have duplicate keys

Comment: That's a typo, I'm trying to add Test4 which doesn't exist. It should be Test3 in the original json.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON_MODIFY()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to add it:

> JSON_MODIFY ( expression , path , newValue )

Use append in the path:

> append - Optional modifier that specifies that the new value should be
> appended to the array referenced by <json path>.

```
DECLARE @jsondata NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @jsondata = '
{
   "Test1":[{"TestValue1":"value1","TestValue2":"value2"}],
   "Test2":[{"TestValue1":"value1","TestValue2":"value2"}],
   "Test3":[{"TestValue1":"value1","TestValue2":"value2"}]
}
'

SET @jsondata = JSON_MODIFY(@jsondata, 'append $.Test4', JSON_QUERY('{"TestValue1":"value1","TestValue2":"value2"}'))

SELECT @jsondata
```

> To avoid automatic escaping, provide newValue by using the JSON_QUERY
> function. JSON_MODIFY knows that the value returned by JSON_MODIFY is
> properly formatted JSON, so it doesn't escape the value.

Which gives you the following results:

```
{
  "Test1": [
    {
      "TestValue1": "value1",
      "TestValue2": "value2"
    }
  ],
  "Test2": [
    {
      "TestValue1": "value1",
      "TestValue2": "value2"
    }
  ],
  "Test3": [
    {
      "TestValue1": "value1",
      "TestValue2": "value2"
    }
  ],
  "Test4": [
    {
      "TestValue1": "value1",
      "TestValue2": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The path argument is what I was missing. I need to use a variable for the path and have found out it isn't supported on my sql 2016 install but is on 2017.